# Grok filter is not working when id has dashes

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I have a sample input like below.

```
[2022-01-06 19:51:42,143] [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG  [50a4f8740c30b9ca,c1b11682-1eeb-4538-b7f6-d0fb261b3e1d]
```

I implemented a grok filter to validate the text.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}  \[%{WORD:traceId},%{WORD:correlationId}\]
```

When I validate it, it says there are no matches.
But If I remove - in correlation id, that filter is working fine. Is there any modification to do to the filter to accept - in the correlation id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{DATA:threadName}\] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}  \[%{DATA:traceId},%{DATA:correlationId}\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [this](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/ecs-v1/grok-patterns) `%{WORD}` pattern is defined by this regular expression `\b\w+\b`

- `\w` captures alphanumeric
- `\b` captures word boundaries. It helps you to perform `whole words only`

So if your original text contains a `-` it will never be capturing it.

You can try `%{DATA}` instead as it captures `.*?`